# Iwasawa Theoretic Interest in a certain type of result

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, iwasawa-theory

This question is probably going to sound vague (since it does to me) and I wish I could make it more precise, but here goes. For $p\in \{107, 139, 271,379\}$ Ohtani and Blondeau (in separate papers) have constructed certain interesting $p$-adic Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{\infty}})$. In greater detail, it is shown in [Blondeau - Lifting of nearly extraordinary Galois representations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X12002727) that for such a prime $p$, there exists a Galois extension $E/\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{\infty}})$ which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that

1. $\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Z}_p)\simeq \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.
2. $E$ is ramified at primes of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{\infty}})$ above only a finite number of rational primes, i.e., there is a finite set of rational primes $S$ such that if $\mathfrak{l}$ is a prime of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{\infty}})$ which is ramified in $E$, then $\mathfrak{l}\mid l$ for $l\in S$.
3. $E$ is tamely ramified at all primes, and unramified at those above $p$.

One reason why such a result is of interest is because of the interest in the tame version of the Fontaine–Mazur conjecture, which roughly states that such a $p$-adic analytic extension which is everywhere tamely ramified and ramified at only finitely many primes cannot exist over a number field. On the other hand, the result shows that it does if one passes up this infinite cyclotomic extension.

I get the sense (from conversations I had) that if the result was to generalize to an arbitrary quadratic fields then it could also be of some interest to an Iwasawa theorist. Is there some truth in this?